# Atomicity of IF and the following statement

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, lock-free

This is A. Williams C++ Concurrency in Action book, lock-free stack with hazard pointers topic. Suppose I gain an understanding of it, except for just two lines, here they are (the [source](https://github.com/niepiekm/CppCiA/blob/master/listing_7.6.cpp) here):

```
// code before
if (old_head) {
res.swap(old_head->data);
// code after
```

The question is: can another thread delete (modify etc.) "old_head" pointer before it is dereferenced (old_head->data)? The logic says no cause the whole Williams' code is erroneous, but I doubt if it's a kind of an atomic operation. What do you think?

Comment: http://preshing.com/20120612/an-introduction-to-lock-free-programming/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `old_head` is available for multiple threads and quoted code block is not protected by any synchronization mechanism, then yes `old_head` could be modified between checking and dereferencing. `if` statement by itself does not guarantee any atomicity.